# View Controllers, Popup buttons, AppDelegates, Status Menus, and headaches

Tags: objective-c, macos, osx-mavericks

This is kinda long but I want to give as many details as possible.

I have created a status bar app. One of the things I've done is made it to where there is a "Settings" menu item that if you click on, an NSWindow pops up with 5 different buttons -- these buttons are tied to their own custom NSViewController so that if you click them, the View Controller changes, but the window remains the same, just like any other StatusBar app.

On one of the view controllers is a popup button with several user selectable options. If I add a button to the specific VC (view controller) and link that to an ibaction that pulls the selected index of the popup button, it works just fine (i.e. I select item 2, it logs item 2).

Now here's where things get. . . odd. I've created a submenu that would in theory allow the user to quickly change the selected item of the popup linked to my custom view controller. Think of this submenu as being labeled 1-4 and clicking one of those items would change the index of the popup button, however every time I try this and follow it up with a NSLog to ensure the button has changed, it ALWAYS reads zero, in other words, it NEVER changes.

Here's what I tried.

1. Just like with every other view controller I've ever used, I create a new object of my view controller (alloc, init), and reference the popup button object that i've created as a property. This compiles just fine, but returns only zero no matter what is selected.
2. I've tried calling the method that I know works (the button that is on the view controller containing the popup), but again, this returns only zero no matter what is selected.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

tl;dr: can't change a popupbutton on a view controller from the app delegate or nsstatusmenu item, it just always returns zero.

EDIT: I have found a work around since I can communicate to my app delegate just fine, I created an int property and set it to zero. From there, whenever my popupbutton on my VC changes, I change the value of the app delegate int property and just ensure that whenever the nib launches, it set's the selected item to the app delegate property. I feel there has to be a more straight forward way to just get the value of the popup and change it from the app delegate.

EDIT 2: Some code as requested. I realized I needed to point the the view controller by using initwithnibname from the app delegate and then load the view. Doing so allows me to pull the first object in the popup button, any subsequent changes are not recognized unless I do so via my test button on the view controller itself. Also, I'm adding values to my popup in my awakefromnib in the view controller.

```
    searches_VC = [[Searches_ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"Searches_ViewController" bundle:nil];
    [searches_VC loadView];
    NSLog(@"Selected Title: %@",[[searches_VC profilePopupOutlet] titleOfSelectedItem]);
```

Comment: 1 line of code is worth a 1000 words ...

Comment: There are many lines of codes, which in particular would you like to see? The 1/2 examples?

Comment: we want to see relevant code, not read 4 or 5 paragraphs

Comment: I have added the code and details that should help. Let me know if you need to see anything else.